# What is the correct location for a maintained virtualenv service?

Tags: 12.04, server, python, virtualenv

I will be installing and maintaining a Python 2.7-based server application on Ubuntu server (12.04). The model of maintenance will be to create a virtualenv and install application standard libraries (from PyPI) and custom libraries (bespoke) there, updating them as required. A separate folder holds the "application", which is made up of configuration files and application-specific Python files.

As far as I can tell, the only Ubuntu-provided packages I require are `python` and `python-virtualenv`. I may do a custom installation of [pew](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pew) to manage the venv - in which case I will `sudo easy_install pew` and accept that wherever it goes is correct (pew isn't in the 12.04 repo).

I have a vague awareness that applications should live in `/opt` or `/srv` or somewhere like that, and that a server application may live in a different location to a user application. Give all that:

- where should the virtualenv be located?
- where should the server application folder be located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Django applications, [Adam Bard recommends](http://adambard.com/blog/start-to-finish-serving-mysql-backed-django-w/) locating your virtualenv at `/opt/apps/<appname>-env` and your application proper at `/opt/apps/<appname>-env/site`. (Many thanks to don.joey for the excellent link.)

Slightly unrelated, I also found Hynek Schlawack's [Python Deployment Anti-Patterns](https://hynek.me/articles/python-deployment-anti-patterns/) and [Python Application Deployment with Native Packages](https://hynek.me/articles/python-app-deployment-with-native-packages/) to be useful reads.

Based on this, my own review of the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) and an inspection of the `/opt` folder on my desktop machine, I went with:

- `/opt/virtualenv/<env_name>` for the virtual environment
- `/opt/<vendor_name>/<app_name>` for the server application folder

This allows me to create multiple independent virtualenvs and application folders for different applications, versions, etc as I see fit.

Comment: When the virtual environment is created inside /opt, how do you use pip? I heard using pip with sudo is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially the location of the virtualenv is irrelevant. You can place it wherever you want. You just have to run `source some_venv/bin/activate` and then you're set to go.

The traditional location is ~/.virtualenvs.

I use a different setup where I have a ~/projects folder which contains the different virtualenvs *and* contains the python code for different projects. This is nice and easy because you have everything together. For some it might look a bit cluttered, because you get a bin, local, and more folders in your venv.

I manage these using [virtualenvwrapper](http://roundhere.net/journal/virtualenv-ubuntu-12-10/) which is in the repos. I did not get the chance to test pew, yet.

If virtualenvwrapper and virtualenv are set up correctly, the workflow is:

```
mkvirtualenv some_venv
workon some_venv
cdvirtualenv
deactivate
```

Comment: I use a similar system for development, but I have this impression that on a production system (or when an application is "installed") things are supposed to live in /opt/ or /srv/ or somewhere like that?

Comment: I am not sure I can answer that. Can you read http://adambard.com/blog/start-to-finish-serving-mysql-backed-django-w/